# How to implement detour functions in Linux

Tags: c++, c, gcc

My requirement is to patch a function during runtime which is equivalent to K-Patch but for application code.
in K-Patch vedio ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=juyQ5TsJRTA ) it mentioned @ 1:41 it using functionality which used for traditional used for tracing (noop) beginning of the function.
where we can register the handler to call new function definition.

In Windows It looks something like this: (http://www.ragestorm.net/blogs/?p=17)

```
0005951e (01) 90                      NOP
0005951f (01) 90                       NOP
00059520 (01) 90                      NOP
00059521 (01) 90                      NOP
00059522 (01) 90                      NOP
00059523 (02) 8bff                   MOV EDI, EDI
00059525 (01) 55                      PUSH EBP
00059526 (02) 8bec                  MOV EBP, ESP
```

I wrote a simple function in Linux (2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64) in which i dont see any NOP instruction which we can used to dynamically patch a new function.

```
0000000000400554 <mysym>:
400554:       55                      push   %rbp
400555:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
400558:       b8 98 06 40 00          mov    $0x400698,%eax
40055d:       be 9b 06 40 00          mov    $0x40069b,%esi
400562:       48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
400565:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
40056a:       e8 c9 fe ff ff          callq  400438 <printf@plt>
40056f:       c9                      leaveq 
400570:       c3                      retq
```

Is there any compiler options or equivalent instructions exists in linux where every functions has some NOP instructions which used to hook up a new function by replacing NOP with near/far JUMP?

Comment: If you know the functions at compile time, you can manually insert NOPs using the `asm` statement. But be aware that this prevents the compiler from using lots of optimisations.

Comment: FYI, Detours isn't dependent on having `NOP`s at the start of a function. IIRC it disassembles the function's prologue to get a large enough space for a jump to a trampoline (and to copy those instructions out). See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/10458162

Comment: If you have the source so you can recompile with `__attribute__((ms_hook_prologue))`, why don't you just insert c(++) code to call a function pointer if it is not `0`?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you can't use `LD_PRELOAD` to replace the function at load time (and `dlsym` to call the original) instead of waiting until runtime?

Answer (score 2):

The question is less a "Linux" one but more a "GCC" one.

GCC provides the `ms_hook_prologue` function attribute [(online reference)](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) which is pretty much the same as the `/hotpatch` compiler option for `cl.exe` (the MS compiler) but on a function level.

Example:

```
__attribute__((ms_hook_prologue)) void foo() { }
```

If you want to use this on more than a few functions you could create a macro to hide the attribute:

```
#define HOTPATCHABLE    __attribute__((ms_hook_prologue))
```

Comment: I hate to ask this but if I define as you have mentioned gcc is throwing an warning1.c:16: warning: ms_hook_prologue attribute directive ignored
1.c:16: error: expected token
distcc[48256] ERROR: compile 1.c on localhost failed. could you please let me know I am missing any header file to include so that these warning go off.

Comment: Depending on your version of GCC you will have to put the attribute in front of the function like this `__attribute__((ms_hook_prologue)) void foo() { }`. For an example look at [this online demo](http://ideone.com/qGBm3H). I'll update my post later.

Comment: Another source of that sort of that error could be that you have a forward declaration of that function and specified the attribute at the wrong place. IIRC you must specify the attribute *only* at the forward declaration.

Comment: Thanks :). I was able to compile and take a objdump.00000000004007c0 <_Z3foov>:
  4007c0:       48 8d a4 24 00 00 00    lea    0x0(%rsp),%rsp
  4007c7:       00 
  4007c8:       55                      push   %rbp
  4007c9:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  4007cc:       be d0 08 40 00          mov    $0x4008d0,%esi
  4007d1:       bf 60 10 60 00          mov    $0x601060,%edi
  4007d6:       e8 c5 fe ff ff          callq  4006a0  
I dont see NOP is LEA load the effective address should I replace LEA to JMP ?

Comment: @Anil yes, `lea` is often used as a multi-byte `nop`. Interestingly, with `gcc -s` you can see that the assembly is emitted as a `.byte` sequence rather than actual instructions, probably to avoid peephole optimizations.